# Watch for change event in Google Calendar for 2way sync

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

Iam now working in Google Calendar api for creating a multiple calendar sync on that i want to perform incremental sync.

So i try watch event function so i refer google calendar doc https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push

On that doc we want to gave request like id,type, address but i won't have idea to how to create url and what are details will gave inside url how to create post request for get notifications